# Reorder created divs Numerically

Tags: javascript, html

How can I reorder the divs Numerically once they are created. Right now it creates them in the random order that the questions are populated.  I need reorder them by the number within the div. ex 1, 2, etc. (Without adding a class or id to that particular div.)  Any help would be appreciated.  (P.S. I cant use jQuery only Javascript.)  The Divs are created near the bottom of the reviewQuiz function.

HTML:

```
<div id="reviewinfo">
   <div>2 Ouestion?
   Correct Answer: 2D
   Your Answer: 2C
   Review:pg2</div>

   <div>1 Question?
   Correct Answer: 1D
   Your Answer: 1C
   Review:pg1</div>

   <div>3 Question?
   Correct Answer: 3D
   Your Answer: 3C
   Review:pg3</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    function reviewQuiz(quiz){
    var thisAr = [];
    var scrollR = document.getElementById("scrollR");
    var reviewInfo = document.createElement("div");
    reviewInfo.setAttribute("id", "reviewInfo");
    scrollR.appendChild(reviewInfo);
    for (var i=0; i<quiz.length; i++) {
        for (var j=0; j<quiz[i].distractors.length; j++) {
            if (quiz[i].distractors[j].selected == true) {
                var selAns = quiz[i].distractors[j].delm;
            }
            if (quiz[i].distractors[j].delm.className == "correct"){
                var correctAns = quiz[i].distractors[j].delm;
            }
            if (quiz[i].distractors[j].id == "form") {
                selAns.innerHTML = document.getElementById("answer1").value;
            }
        }
        //reviewSort();

        var afb; 
        var rev;
        var rpage = quiz[i].qelm.className;
        var x = "p" + i;

        if (selAns.innerHTML == correctAns.innerHTML) {
            afb = "Correct Answer: " + correctAns.innerHTML;
            rev = "";
        }else{  afb = "Correct Answer: " + correctAns.innerHTML + "<br>Your Answer: " + selAns.innerHTML;
            rev ='<p>Review:' + rpage + '</p>';
        }

        document.getElementById("reviewInfo").innerHTML += '<div id="' + x +'" class="sortme">' + rev + quiz[i].qelm.innerHTML + '<blockquote>' + afb + '</blockquote></div>';
        //alert(i);
        if (selAns.innerHTML == correctAns.innerHTML) { 
            document.getElementById(x).style.background = "url(gui/check.png) no-repeat 1% 80% #444";
        } else {
            var thisq = document.getElementById(x); 
            thisq.style.background = "url(gui/X.png) no-repeat 1% 80% #444";
        }


    }

    addReviewHandles();
}

function addReviewHandles(){
    var quiz = quizObj();
    for (var i=0; i<quiz.length; i++) {
        var btn = document.getElementById("p"+i).getElementsByTagName("p");
        if (btn[0]){
            btn[0].onclick = (function(num){
                return function() { //return function for i scope
                    var rpage = quiz[num].qelm.className;
                    document.getElementById("returnQuiz").style.display = "block";//alert(rpage);
                    window.gotoPage(window[rpage].number);
                }
            })(i);//alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the `reviewinfo` div as it is in your question, take the children of it and put it into an array, then sort the array by comparing the first digit of the child's text. Then you can append each element to the `reviewinfo` in order:

```js
const reviewinfo = document.querySelector('#reviewinfo');
const questions = [...reviewinfo.children];
const getQuestionNumber = div => Number(div.textContent.match(/^\d+/)[0]);
questions.sort((a, b) => getQuestionNumber(a) - getQuestionNumber(b));
for (const question of questions)  {
  reviewinfo.appendChild(question);
}
```

```html
<div id="reviewinfo">
   <div>5 Question?
   Correct Answer: 3D
   Your Answer: 3C
   Review:pg3</div>
   <div>2 Ouestion?
   Correct Answer: 2D
   Your Answer: 2C
   Review:pg2</div>

   <div>1 Question?
   Correct Answer: 1D
   Your Answer: 1C
   Review:pg1</div>

   <div>3 Question?
   Correct Answer: 3D
   Your Answer: 3C
   Review:pg3</div>
   <div>4 Question?
   Correct Answer: 3D
   Your Answer: 3C
   Review:pg3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I missed this. Is there a way to do it without const? For some reason it doesn't recognize it.

Comment: `const` is ES2015 syntax. If your IDE doesn't understand ES2015 in 2020, you should strongly consider updating it to something less ancient. If you want to transpile ES2015+ code to ES5, use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to turn the (nice-looking, modern) code into (ugly) production code automatically.

Comment: In any browser from the past 5 years, you should be able to press the "Run code snippet" button and see the code working as desired in the answer above.